# Adding numbers to references with authoryear citation style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

My document is based on the `report` class. I am using custom `bibtex` style file generated through `makebst` for my thesis and the citation style I need is `authoryear`. The references are to be sorted alphabetically. The problem is I'm not getting numerical list of the references. I need numerical listing of references as shown in the figure below

[image: university_format]

For the moment, I get the list of references without numerical listing, as shown in the figure below.
[image: without_numerical_listing]

Comment: Would a `biblatex` solution be acceptable for you?

Comment: @Corentin Please suggest for BiBTeX. Since If i want to follow BiBLaTeX, i should start it from beginning.

Comment: @Corentin Thanks, We have prepared BiBLaTeX style files as per our needs.It works fine.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it helped. There may be a pure BibTeX solution, but if you are happy with the BibLaTeX one, I think it is the most simple.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, may I kindly suggest that you mark it as accepted (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)), so that the question doesn't appear as unanswered anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are ready to use `biblatex`, the following example has a numbered, alphabetically sorted list of references, with author-year citation style:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=numeric,firstinits=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A2012,
author = {Author, A},
title = {An interesting paper},
journal = {Journal},
year = {2012},
volume = {2},
pages = {70--76},
}
@article{B2012,
author = {Buthor, B},
title = {An also interesting paper},
journal = {Journal},
year = {2012},
volume = {2},
pages = {77--79},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

\autocite{B2012}

\autocite{A2012}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]