# Looking for a suitable bibstyle

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I am very new in BibLaTex. I need such a way to cite:

> Tropical cyclones (TCs), referring to hurricanes, typhoons, tropical storms, and weaker tropical depressions (Vitart et. al, 1997).
>
> Reference
>
> [1] Vitart, F., J. L. Anderson, and W. F. Stern, 1997: Simulation of inter-annual variability of tropical storm frequency in an ensemble
> of GCM integrations. J. Climate, 10, 745–760.

What kind of bibstyle should I use? I didn't find anything that meets my requirement.

Thanks a lot!

P.S. In summary, the style that I want to cite should be

Text (author, 2015)

Reference

[#] Author, 2015. *Article name.* Journal name....

This may be most likely to authoryear in BibLaTex. But I still don't know how to use it. Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authoryearbrak]{biblatex}
\begin{document}
   Tropical cyclones (TCs), referring to hurricanes, typhoons, tropical storms, and weaker tropical depressions \parencite{Bengtsson-L.:1982aa}. 

\addbibresource{2016MOST_Paper_JRA25TC_20160201.bib} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

But it's not work. I use BibDesk with my work.

Comment: Hi. If you are new to LaTeX and bibtex take a look at the package "BibLaTeX", especially at the different styles that come with it.
edit://
The manual of biblatex with the basic styles on page 63pp.: ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf

If you can't find a suitable style, this package allows imho the easiest creation of own styles.

Comment: Which citation style do you want to use?

Comment: In the text: (author, 2015); 

Reference: [#] Author, 2015: Article_name. Publisher.......

Comment: I google it and find out the possible BibLatex style that I may use: authoryear. But I still have no idea how to use it.

Comment: For a general introduction read [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864) as well as the questions linked to there if you are coming from BibTeX read [What to do to switch to biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864) or if not [How to learn biblatex without knowing BibTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118613/35864).

Comment: The general idea of the style you ask for confuses me a bit (why would you want author-year *and* numbers?), but there are amongst others [Biblatex enumerating sorted bibliography (using authoryear-ibid style)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24501/35864), [biblatex-biber: How to customize the order in the bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/248726/35864), [Adding numbers to references with authoryear citation style](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74894/35864), [Adding numbers to Author Year citations in list of references](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61374/35864)

Comment: I mainly need authoryear style. Number is not necessary. I will try to read the reference you provided to find out the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Any news here? Can we mark this as solved? Did the linked questions help you? If not, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MWE is of no use since we do not have the contents of your *.bib file. My guess would be that you need to switch your bibliography parser to 'biber'. Does your MWE work with the following adjustments?

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authoryearbrak,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

If yes, you should change the bibliography tool of your editor to biber and change the

```
backend=bibtex
```

to

```
backend=biber
```

Comment: Admitted the example by the O.P. is not really useful, but does this really answer the question?

Comment: You are right. It was an uneducated guess from my own experience.

Comment: Please note that the (cite)style `authoryearbrak` (i.e. `authoryearbrak.cbx`) does not exist on CTAN, the only reference to such a file I could find on github: https://github.com/tehingo/literature-study, but these files haven't been touched in the last two years.